# ActionListener & MouseListener confliction

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, listener, actionlistener, mouselistener

I am trying to make my application minimize on taskbar and restore when I double click on the  `trayIcon`. I also have a popup menu that has an item which restores the window when clicked.

```
    trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Anything", popup);
    trayIcon.addActionListener(actionListener);
    trayIcon.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    sysTray.add(trayIcon);
```

And here is the code of the `actionListener` and `mouseListener`:

```
private ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener()
{
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
   {
      if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Restore"))
      { // RIGHT CLICK -> RESTORE
        // Do something
      }
   }
};

private MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener()
{
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
   {
       if (javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) && e.getClickCount()>1)                                                  
       {  // DOUBLE LEFT MOUSE CLICK
          // Do something
       }
    }
    // Rest of the code
 }
```

The `Restore` option of the popup menu works fine, however when I am double-clicking on the `trayIcon` at the System Tray I get a `Null Pointer Exception` at line `if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Restore"))`

**How can I eliminate this and if possible merge both listeners into one?**

Comment: Why do you even need the mouse listener or check the action command? The action listener is invoked only on double click / keyboard selection

Comment: I am checking the ActionEvent because I have more than one menu items and I need to distinguish between them, I have omitted the code for the rest though. The ActionListener is also invoked when I select one of the items of the menu. However you are right about the MouseListener, in fact I am looking for a way to implement the MouseListener into the ActionListener.

Comment: I personally dislike the practice of using a single `ActionListener` for different actions. One of the reasons is that it forces the same info in all events, even if it's not applicable. This is one of those cases - the trayIcon simply doesn't populate the `ActionCommand`. The solution I implemented was using a single `RestoreListener` that just restored the frame without any checks, and put that listener on the restore menu item and trayIcon **only**.

Comment: Ok, I did as you said and it works with a minor flaw. Now, when I double click on the trayIcon the window *is* restored however it doesn't have focus, unlike the "Restore" option which restores the window **and** provides focus, although they both run the same code essentially. Any workarounds?

Comment: Interesting... Unfortunately I won't be able to actually test any solutions until Monday, but: did you try to `requestFocus()` on the frame through a `WindowListener`?

Comment: Yes, I finanlly solved this, the trick is to call .toTop() when you make the window visible, requestFocus() doesn't seem to change the focus state at all. Please make a detailed answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*N.B. This answer is made from a conversation with the OP in the comments, and some of the solutions came from the OP*

The `TrayIcon` does not populate the `ActionCommand` field when firing the event, hence the code dies with an NPE.

Since the tray icon only calls its `ActionListener` only when double clicked or in an analagous action (via keyboard), you can create a `RestoreListener` that does not check that condition at all, and is only used with the tray icon and the "Restore" menu item.

```
private ActionListener restoreListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Do the actual restoration
    }
};
```

And actually adding it to the items...

```
trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Anything", popup);
trayIcon.addActionListener(restoreListener);

MenuItem restoreMenuItem = new MenuItem(...);
restoreMenuItem.addActionListener(restoreListener);
```

This seems to behave slightly differently from a `MouseListener` that it does not put the window on top, this can be remedied by calling `toTop()` on it.